# How to remove the border of fields from the form using a button

Tags: javascript, html, border

How to do that after sending the form and display in places where there were form fields the entered data that come from these form fields and delete. I wanted to use preventdefault ()

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
           <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <form novalidate>
            <label for="imie">Name</label>
            <INPUT type="text" id="firstName"><BR>
            <div id="first-name-err"></div>
          
           <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
           </form>
           <script>
   var firstName= document.getElementById("firstName");
          var firstNameValidation=function(){
          firstNameValue=firstName.value.trim();
          validFirstName=/^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,}/mg;
          firstNameErr=document.getElementById('first-name-err');
          if(firstNameValue=="")
          {
           }else if(!validFirstName.test(firstNameValue)){
            firstNameErr.innerHTML="...h";
          }else{
            firstNameErr.innerHTML="";
            return true;
          
          }
        }
          firstName.oninput=function(){
         
          firstNameValidation();
        }
      
           </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```